# iTunes Connect: Contains Encryption?

Tags: c#, ios, app-store-connect

I want an update pushed out to my game pretty soon, but I'm stuck on this question. I added a small function that essentially uses RNGCryptoServiceProvider() (C# & Unity3D) to generate a small random string that I use to identify the user. It is sent as part of a field in POST data to my mysql server but nothing more.

I want to answer "no" for this question, but I'm scared that apple will somehow detect ("using System.Security.Cryptography" at the top of my C# file) that RNGCryptoServiceProvider() is a part of, and think I'm trying to do something malicious by answering no. Am I being paranoid? Is it safe to answer "no" or should I answer yes? Thanks

Comment: You might be better off asking Apple. Even though they have a review process for apps, stuff can slip past it. So even if someone here has done something similar and gotten past review without saying their app contains encryption, that doesn't mean that's what Apple actually thinks you should do and won't reject it.

Comment: Just answer yes. Its just for government compliance.

Comment: @Schemetrical and BSMP: Why answer yes when no encryption is being used?

Comment: @zaph although generating random numbers is not using encryption, using these functions may lead to a rejection. Responding yes doesn't change anything, they just ask you if its government compliant and you answer yes to that.

Comment: Beats me why just answering the question truthfully is not  good idea. Also it is more involved than just answering yes. You will be asked additional questions which will probably lead you back to "no".

Answer (score 0):

Generating random numbers is not using encryption, you are not encryption anything.

See: [Cryptography and U.S. Export Compliance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW6).